# Image slider on the left, text on the right: HOW?

Tags: html, css, slider

I can't put the image slider on the left side as well as the radio buttons (both manual and auto). I also wanted to put the text beside the image slider.

This is what I created to the image slider. Remember: the background colors that I put is just my guide.

here is the HTML

```css
/**sliders**/
.slider-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: red;
    flex: 1 1 40rem;
}

.slider {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
  
.slides {
    width: 500%;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
}
  
.slides input {
    display: none;
}
  
.slide {
    width: 20%;
    transition: 2s;
}
  
.slide img {
    left: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
  
/**for manual slide nav**/
.nav-manual {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: blue;
}
  
.manual-btn {
    border: 2px solid #add8e7;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
}
  
.manual-btn:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 40px;
}
  
.manual-btn:hover {
    background: #add8e7;
}
  
#radio1:checked ~ .first {
    margin-left: 0;
}
  
#radio2:checked ~ .first {
    margin-left: -20%;
}
  
#radio3:checked ~ .first {
    margin-left: -40%;
}
  
#radio4:checked ~ .first {
    margin-left: -60%;
}
  
/**for automatic nav**/
.nav-auto {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: 700px;
    justify-content: left;
    margin-top: 460px;
}
  
.nav-auto div {
    border: 2px solid #add8e7;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 1s;
}
  
.nav-auto div:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 40px;
}
  
#radio1:checked ~ .nav-auto .auto-btn1 {
    background: #add8e7;
}
  
#radio2:checked ~ .nav-auto .auto-btn2 {
    background: #add8e7;
}
  
#radio3:checked ~ .nav-auto .auto-btn3 {
    background: #add8e7;
}
  
#radio4:checked ~ .nav-auto .auto-btn4 {
    background: #add8e7;
}

.heading {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 2rem 0;
}

.about .row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2rem;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

.about .row .slider-wrapper {
    
    position: relative;
}

.about .row .content {
    flex: 1 1 40rem;
    
}
```

```html
<section class="about" id="about">
    <h1 class="heading">About Us</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <!--image slider start-->
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slides">
                    <!--radio buttons start-->
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio4">
                    <!--radio buttons end-->
                    <!--slide images start-->
                    <div class="slide first">
                        <img src="images/slider-1.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="images/slider-2.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="images/slider-3.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="images/slider-4.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <!--slide images end-->    
                    <!--automatic navigation start-->
                    <div class="nav-auto">
                        <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
                        <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
                        <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
                        <div class="auto-btn4"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!--automatic navigation end-->                          
                </div>
                <!--manual navigation start-->
                <div class="nav-manual">
                    <label for="radio1" class="manual-btn"></label>
                    <label for="radio2" class="manual-btn"></label>
                    <label for="radio3" class="manual-btn"></label>
                    <label for="radio4" class="manual-btn"></label>
                </div>
                <!--manual navigation end-->
            </div>
            <!--image slider end-->
        </div>
    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var counter = 1;
            setInterval(function(){
                document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked = true;
                counter++;
                if(counter > 4){
                    counter - 1;
                }
            }, 5000);
        </script>

    <div class="content">
        <h3>ATF BUILDERS CONSTRUCTION SUPPLY</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Ad nisi minima quis iure molestias nam fugit aspernatur, numquam sed enim.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Porro fugiat placeat natus, distinctio voluptates ex in odit minima aut,
            culpa totam qui facere quasi harum laborum. Laudantium consectetur assumenda
            perspiciatis.</p>
        <a href="#" class="learn-more">Learn More</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

hope you guys would help me. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you can move the `content` element inside the `row` element.
then change `.slider` in css add `position: relative;` then add bottom and left to `.nav-manual` like this `bottom: 0;`, `left: 25%;`

```js
var counter = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked = true;
  counter++;
  if (counter > 4) {
    counter - 1;
  }
}, 5000);
```

```css
/**sliders**/

.slider-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 1 40rem;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slides {
  width: 500%;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
}

.slides input {
  display: none;
}

.slide {
  width: 20%;
  transition: 2s;
}

.slide img {
  left: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}


/**for manual slide nav**/

.nav-manual {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 25%;
}

.manual-btn {
  border: 2px solid #add8e7;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
}

.manual-btn:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.manual-btn:hover {
  background: #add8e7;
}

#radio1:checked~.first {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#radio2:checked~.first {
  margin-left: -20%;
}

#radio3:checked~.first {
  margin-left: -40%;
}

#radio4:checked~.first {
  margin-left: -60%;
}


/**for automatic nav**/

.nav-auto {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 700px;
  justify-content: left;
  margin-top: 460px;
}

.nav-auto div {
  border: 2px solid #add8e7;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.nav-auto div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

#radio1:checked~.nav-auto .auto-btn1 {
  background: #add8e7;
}

#radio2:checked~.nav-auto .auto-btn2 {
  background: #add8e7;
}

#radio3:checked~.nav-auto .auto-btn3 {
  background: #add8e7;
}

#radio4:checked~.nav-auto .auto-btn4 {
  background: #add8e7;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.about .row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2rem;
  //flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

.about .row .slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.about .row .content {
  flex: 1 1 40rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Myfirstwebsite</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="about" id="about">
    <h1 class="heading">About Us</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <!--image slider start-->
        <div class="slider">
          <div class="slides">
            <!--radio buttons start-->
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio4">
            <!--radio buttons end-->
            <!--slide images start-->
            <div class="slide first">
              <img src="slider-1.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="slider-2.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="slider-3.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="slider-4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <!--slide images end-->
            <!--automatic navigation start-->
            <div class="nav-auto">
              <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
              <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
              <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
              <div class="auto-btn4"></div>
            </div>
            <!--automatic navigation end-->
          </div>
          <!--manual navigation start-->
          <div class="nav-manual">
            <label for="radio1" class="manual-btn"></label>
            <label for="radio2" class="manual-btn"></label>
            <label for="radio3" class="manual-btn"></label>
            <label for="radio4" class="manual-btn"></label>
          </div>
          <!--manual navigation end-->
        </div>
        <!--image slider end-->
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>ATF BUILDERS CONSTRUCTION SUPPLY</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad nisi minima quis iure molestias nam fugit aspernatur, numquam sed enim.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro fugiat placeat natus, distinctio voluptates ex in odit minima aut, culpa totam qui facere quasi harum laborum. Laudantium consectetur assumenda perspiciatis.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="learn-more">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```